# How to pass special characters to javascript window.open in URL using paper.add method?

Tags: javascript, raphael, href, window.open

```
paper.add([{
              type: "text",
               x: 340 + textLength + 28,
               y: 410,
               text: "4860",
               fill: "blue", 
                    href:"javascript:window.open('https://planning.partners.com/ep/#Create Campaign&CId=4860');void(0)"
                    }
                ]).attr({ 'font-size': 14, "font-family": "Segoe UI", "text-decoration": "underline", 'text-anchor': "start" });
```

The above code is rendering the text (4860) fine and showing the hyperlink. But when i am clicking on the hyperlink, the window is opening with the URL "https://planning.partners.com/ep/". The special character # and rest of the URL skipped. How to pass special characters to javascript window.open in URL using paper.add method?

Comment: I think you should replace the spaces with `+` first

Comment: Replacing space with + wont solve special character # issue. right?

Comment: No reason that the `#` should be lost form the URL … unless you were expecting to receive it on the server.

Comment: Could you check the generated html code for the presence of the anchor in it? I just tested a simple window.open with anchor and it works perfectly.

Comment: Yes. Generated HTML contains # in the URL. Following is the generated HTML Code

<a href="javascript:window.open('https://planning.partners.com/ep//#Create Campaign&campaignId=4860');void(0)">
 <text xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" font-family="Segoe UI" font-size="14px" style="font: 14px/normal Segoe UI; font-size-adjust: none; font- stretch: normal; text-anchor: start;" fill="#0000ff" stroke="none" text-anchor="start" x="481" y="410" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;">
  <tspan  dy="5.8">4860</tspan></text>

Comment: I tried by replacing the special characters with encoded values like space with %20 and # with %23 but no luck and also tried to construct the URL with escape method for # like -> urlbeforehash + escape('#') + urlafterhash. even this doesn't worked. :(

Comment: @SanthoshA .. there is a differences between 'planning.partners.com/ep//#Create Campaign&campaignId=4860 and https://planning.partners.com/ep/#Create Campaign&CId=4860 check your url path

Comment: @jjj... Sorry, that is just typo error. Even though if the URLs are same it is not working... Struggling with this issue :(

Comment: `start bounty` if you need to solve it desperately