# Javascript window.open cuts off link at special character

Tags: javascript

This is my second question on stackoverflow so please forgive any unintended newbieness.

I checked the suggested duplicate post - [How to pass special characters to javascript window.open in URL using paper.add method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060294/how-to-pass-special-characters-to-javascript-window-open-in-url-using-paper-add)

but that post does not contain an answer.

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to open a file link (my users are all IE) via javascript. Said link may contain a hash character - "#". If it does, the link gets cut off at the hash tag (and does not work, obviously).

I found a way around this by encoding the URI and then opening it in the same window. My requirement is to open it in a new tab. I have not been able to figure out how to do this with window.open().

The below code opens the file in the same window. No good.

```
 $(document).on("click", "#LANPath", function (e) {
    var str = 'J:/Product Compliance/FACTs/+FACTS Test/Test_Attachment_Single_Premium_Group_App_Sample # Copy.pdf';

    var url = encodeURIComponent(str);
    var url2 = url.replace(/#/g, '%23');

    window.location.href = 'file:///' + url2;
});
```

The below function cuts off the url at the # and does not open anything. Worse yet.

```
$(document).on("click", "#LANPath", function (e) {
    var str = 'J:/Product Compliance/FACTs/+FACTS Test/Test_Attachment_Single_Premium_Group_App_Sample # Copy.pdf';

    var url = encodeURIComponent(str);
    var url2 = url.replace(/#/g, '%23');

    var win = window.open( 'file:///' + url2, '_blank');
    win.focus();
});
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `str` is not a URI component, so don't encode it as a URI component.

Comment: If I don't encode it, here's what the path looks like (and still does not work): http://localhost:56670/Instance/Details/file%3A%2F%2F%2FJ:/Product%20Compliance/FACTs/+FACTS%20Test/Test_Attachment_Single_Premium_Group_App_Sample%20%23%20Copy.pdf

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314680/internet-explorer-8-9-window-open-issue  the problem only arises on localhost.

Comment: @phari Nope. Put the .vbhtml on a server, still getting cut off at the # on window.open.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I'll file my answer anyway because I did just today find this same issue.

I was able to replicate this behaviour with Internet Explorer an I managed to circumvent it by splitting the operation in 2 steps: opening the new window and then browsing the desired URL. As in the question context:

```
var win = window.open();
win.location = 'file:///' + url2;
win.focus();
```